# Getting illegalStateException inspite using realm.beginTransaction()

Tags: android, realm

I am getting this error when modifying my model-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.
```

This is my code -

```
Realm realm = ProjectUtil.getRealmWithConfiguration(mActivity);
realm.beginTransaction();

if (something) {
    wordModel.setSomething(something);
} else {
    wordModel.setSomething(false);
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after reading realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realms) multiple times. As it turns out you can't build `RealmConfiguration`  everytime you make `Realm` instance. Instead set default configuration in your application class like -

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("realmFile.realm")
                .encryptionKey("yourKey".getBytes())
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

and every time you want to create a Realm Instance call -

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `RealmObject` is most likely not associated with that given Realm instance, and is possibly associated with a different realm instance. How do you obtain your `wordModel` object? If you create it like so `WordModel wordModel = new WordModel();` then you should use `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(wordModel)` method to copy it to the realm.

Comment: That is how I got the wordModel object
`Realm realm = ProjectUtil.getRealmWithConfiguration(mActivity);
        RealmQuery<WordModel> query = realm.where(WordModel.class);
        RealmResults<WordModel> result1 = query.findAll();
        WordModel wordModel = result1.get(0);`

Comment: That's not how it is on your screenshot though :(

Comment: What does your `ProjectUtil.getRealmWithConfiguration()` method do? If it can return instances that point to different files that would be the problem.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior  `public static Realm getRealmWithConfiguration(Context context) {
        RealmConfiguration config0 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("default")
                .migration(new Migration())
                .encryptionKey("mykey".getBytes())
                .build();
        return Realm.getInstance(config0);
    }`